# Linear regression coefficient when residuals are regressed against each other

Tags: regression, residuals, linear

Suppose we have two variables $X_2$ and $X_3$ and two regressions are run:

$$X_2=a+bX_3+v_2$$

and

$$X_3=c+dX_2+v_3$$

$v_2$ and $v_3$ are the observed residuals.

Can we say if we regress $v_3$ on $v_2$, the coefficient of $v_2$ will be $d$? Is there a way this can be shown?

Comment: What are $v2$ and $v3$ in your models? They look like error terms, which you cannot observe.

Comment: They are the observed residuals. Sorry forgot to mention. I've added it now.

Comment: Have you tried some analytical solution?

Comment: Please check if my edit solve your problem.

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks!

Comment: If my answer is what you were looking for you are invited to accept it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a hint, consider this simulation in R:

```
rm(list=ls())
set.seed(42)

n=1000
x3= rnorm(n)
x2 = 1 + 2 * x3 + rnorm(n)

lm(x2 ~ x3)
Coefficients:
(Intercept)    x3  
  0.9949       2.0098

# let's store the residual v2: 
v2 = lm(x2~x3)$res

# now let's consider the second model:
lm(x3~x2)
Coefficients:
(Intercept)   x2  
-0.4044       0.4014

# and store the residual v3:
v3 = lm(x3~x2)$res

# let's regress v3 on v2:
lm(v3~v2)
Coefficients:
(Intercept)    v2  
 -2.255e-17   -4.014e-01
```

They're not equal but they look related.

**Edit:**

Plug the equation of $X_2$ in the second model and isolate $v_3$. You will see that the parameter on $v_2$ is $-d$.

Answer (score 2):

From the first regression, we have $$X_3 = -\frac{a}{b} + \frac{1}{b} X_2 - \frac{v_2}{b}$$
Comparing this with $$ X_3 = c + dX_2 + v_3$$

and assuming the two regressions are performed similarly, we have $$c = -\frac{a}{b}$$ $$d = \frac{1}{b} $$ and $$v_3 = \frac{-1}{b}v2$$

Therefore we have $$v3 = -d v2$$